# TypeScript - Set both default value and available values for class property

Tags: typescript

I have a question is that how I can set the class property's default value and all available values in once. For example:

```js
class MyClass{
  isActive = -1; //Set default value
}

class MyClass{
  isActive: -1 | 0 | 1; //Set all available value
}

And I want to do sth like this:
class MyClass{
  //isActive = -1 && isActive: -1 | 0 | 1
}
```

Comment: _Set all available value_ is setting a type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the syntax:

```
class MyClass {
    isActive: -1 | 0 | 1 = -1;
}
```

Just like it would be with a standalone variable name.

```
let isActive: -1 | 0 | 1 = -1;
```